# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelectorAll') VS Code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a responsive product card with a quick view product preview popup. It works one time but after I refresh I get this **Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelectorAll')**

**Here is my code:**

```
`import React from 'react'
import './ServiceP.css'
// import './service-script.js'

import {FaTimes} from 'react-icons/fa'

const ServiceP = () => {
    return (
        <div className='service'>
            <div className="container">
                <p>Service</p>
                <h2>Purrrfection At Its Finest!</h2>

                {/* Row 1 */}
                <div className="card-container">

                        <div className="polaroid" data-name="p-1">
                            <img src={pic1} alt="pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                            <div className="container">
                                <p>French Tip</p>
                                <h3>Click For Prices</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="polaroid" data-name="p-2">
                            <img src={pic2} alt="pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                            <div className="container">
                                <p>Acrylic Fullset</p>
                                <h3>Click For Prices</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="polaroid" data-name="p-3">
                            <img src={pic3} alt="pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                            <div className="container">
                                <p>Add Ons</p>
                                <h3>Click For Prices</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                {/* Row 2 */}
                <div className="card-container" >
                        <div className="polaroid" data-name="p-4">
                            <img src={pic4} alt="pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                            <div className="container">
                                <p>Manicures & Overlays</p>
                                <h3>Click For Prices</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="polaroid" data-name="p-5">
                            <img src={pic5} alt="pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                            <div className="container">
                                <p>Fills</p>
                                <h3>Click For Prices</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="polaroid" data-name="p-6">
                            <img src={pic6} alt="pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                            <div className="container">
                                <p>Soak Off</p>
                                <h3>Click For Prices</h3>
                                <h4>(Only for nails that are done by me)</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                </div>
            </div>

        {/* ------------------ Creating pop up pricing page --------------------- */}
            <div class="price-preview">
                <div className="preview" data-target="p-1">
                    {<FaTimes className='icon-times' />}
                    <img src={pic1} alt="preview-pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                    <p>French Tip</p>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Classic French Tip: $15</h5>
                        <h5>V-Cut French Tip: $15</h5>
                        <h5>Deep French Tip: $10</h5>
                        <h5>Tapered Square French Tip: $10</h5>
                    </div>
                    <Link className='btn' to="/BookMe">Book Me</Link>
                </div>

                <div className="preview" data-target="p-2">
                    {<FaTimes className='icon-times' />}
                    <img src={pic1} alt="preview-pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                    <p>Acrylic Fullset</p>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Classic French Tip: $15</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>V-Cut French Tip: $15</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>Deep French Tip: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>Tapered Square French Tip: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                    </div>
                    <Link className='btn' to="/BookMe">Book Me</Link>
                </div>

                <div className="preview" data-target="p-3">
                    {<FaTimes className='icon-times' />}
                    <img src={pic1} alt="preview-pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                    <p>Add Ons</p>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Classic French Tip: $15</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>V-Cut French Tip: $15</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>Deep French Tip: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>Tapered Square French Tip: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                    </div>
                    <Link className='btn' to="/BookMe">Book Me</Link>
                </div>

                <div className="preview" data-target="p-4">
                    {<FaTimes className='icon-times' />}
                    <img src={pic1} alt="preview-pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                    <p>Manicures & Overlays</p>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Classic French Tip: $15</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>V-Cut French Tip: $15</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>Deep French Tip: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>Tapered Square French Tip: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                    </div>
                    <Link className='btn' to="/BookMe">Book Me</Link>
                </div>

                <div class="preview" data-target="p-5">
                    {<FaTimes className='icon-times' />}
                    <img src={pic1} alt="preview-pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                    <p>Fills</p>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Classic French Tip: $15</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>V-Cut French Tip: $15</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>Deep French Tip: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h5>Tapered Square French Tip: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                    </div>
                    <Link className='btn' to="/BookMe">Book Me</Link>
                </div>

                <div className="preview" data-target="p-6">
                    {<FaTimes className='icon-times' />}
                    <img src={pic1} alt="preview-pic" width="300" height="300"/>
                    <p>Soak Off</p>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Soak Off: $10</h5><Link to="/"><h3>Book Now</h3></Link>
                        <h4>(Only for nails that are done by me)</h4>
                    </div>
                    <Link className='btn' to="/BookMe">Book Me</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}`
```

**Code in JS:**

```
`let pricePreview = document.querySelector('.price-preview');
let previewBox = pricePreview.querySelectorAll('.preview');

document.querySelectorAll('.card-container .polaroid ').forEach(polaroid =>{
    polaroid.onclick = () =>{
        pricePreview.style.display = 'flex';
    let name = polaroid.getAttribute('data-name');
    previewBox.forEach(preview =>{
        if(preview === !null){
            let target = preview.getAttribute('data-target');
        if(name === target){
        preview.classList.add('active');
      }
        }
      
    });
  };
});

previewBox.forEach(close =>{
  close.querySelector('.fa-times').onclick = () =>{
    close.classList.remove('active');
    pricePreview.style.display = 'none';
  };
});`
```

Ive tried everything I could possibly think of on my end. Ive been researching for the past week what to do. Still can't figure it out.

Comment: So pricePreview is null meaning it did not find the element. So you are reading the element before it is probably rendered. Not sure why you would be doing this in a react app.

Comment: Okay thank you. Im new to React. My first time creating a website with it. @epascarello

Comment: Hmm. So, your `service-script.js` is probably loading and running before React. `pricePreview` won't exist if React hasn't rendered anything yet. It's a bit unclear how you're trying to use React here. Any more detail on why you have the separate script or what you're looking to achieve? For example, you could just use React to make your life easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the code from `service-script.js` inside the `ServiceP` component. But this is not React way. Do something like this : `<div onClick={changePreviewStyle} role="button" className="polaroid" data-name="p-1">...</div>`

`const changePreviewStyle = () => {...your code}`

BTW using `div` as a button is not great idea. Check this [article](https://www.builder.io/blog/buttons) and new (still beta) [React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much. Like I said I'm new to react so Im just trying to learn on the fly. That you for your help.